# Set buffer-local variable in buffer other than the current one?

Tags: variables, buffer-local

I'm in buffer **A** and I want to set a buffer-local variable in buffer **B**. I'm currently doing:

```
(with-current-buffer B
  (setq-local some-var 'some-val))
```

but is there a way to do this without changing the current buffer, i.e. can I explicitly specify the buffer whose value I want to change?

Comment: Good idea. I just submitted an enhancement request for this: bug #[26923](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26923).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is correct.

> is there a way to do this without changing the current buffer, i.e. can I explicitly specify the buffer whose value I want to change?

While there is nothing built in, you can trivially write a macro which takes all three arguments, and then does exactly what you were doing.

Comment: `(setf (buffer-local-value 'some-var B) 'some-val)` might qualify as a builtin macro for this.

Comment: Ah, the magic of setf places. Thanks npostavs. You should post that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 9):

> is there a way to do this without changing the current buffer

No, but `buffer-local-value` is a [Generalized Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html), so you can use `setf` to take care of the buffer switching for you:

```el
(setf (buffer-local-value 'some-var B) 'some-val)
```

This macroexpands to essentially the same code as what your wrote above:

```el
(let* ((#1=#:v B))
  (with-current-buffer #1#
    (set (make-local-variable 'some-var) 'some-val)))
```

Comment: Cool. Now that I know there are two ways to do this, the inevitable question is "which is faster?" I guess I can try it out both ways and compare.

Comment: @ivan The `setf` just macroexpands to pretty much the same code you wrote, there's no point in worrying about performance for something like this.